# Using Same Node ids for Different Content Type Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

Is it possible to use different node ids for different content types. Consider two content types Questions and Quizzes. I want each question and quiz has its own node id starting from one. Is there a module that can do this.?

**Expected Result:**

*Question Table*

Node Id,Question

1,Define Speed

2,Define Gravity

*Quiz Table*

Node Id,Quiz

1,Phy Quiz 1

2,Phy Quiz 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Node Ids this way. [Serial Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/serial) Module can help with this. Each content type will have its unique id starting form 1.